# Upgrading to Windows 10 from windows Vista Home

Tags: windows, installation

All my home computers are running Windows 10.  Is there a way I can upgrade to Windows 10 on my laptop that is running Windows Vista Home Premium?

Comment: There is no direct free upgrade path from Windows Vista to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you’ll have to buy Windows 10 and install it from scratch. Because  Windows Vista Home Premium is an old operating system of which no upgrade is now available as you can read from this [documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/upgrade-to-another-edition-of-windows-vista):

> Windows Anytime Upgrade is no longer available for Windows Vista.

On the right side of the page I linked to, you can read:

> Applies to these editions of Windows Vista:
>
> - Home Premium
> - Business

Comment: "you’ll have to buy Windows 10 and install it from scratch": No you don't **have** to - you can also buy/install any of Windows 7, 8, or 8.1 and then upgrade for free.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, you are right. It's an option.