# Windows Vista to 10 upgrade using windows 7 key?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-10-upgrade

I have a Windows Vista laptop that I want to upgrade to Windows 10. I found a webshop that sells OEM keys for both Windows 10 Professional and Windows 7 Professional. The latter is cheaper and contains a free upgrade to 10.

I downloaded the USB installer for Windows 10 from the Microsoft website. Can I successfully run this installer using an unused Windows 7 Professional OEM key, or do I have to install Windows 7 first?

When I looked for answers on this site, I found conflicting answers ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/1022389/avoiding-upgrade-chain-when-getting-windows-10-free-upgrade-vista-win7-wi)/[2](https://superuser.com/questions/1011972/upgrading-to-windows-10-from-windows-vista-home)/[3](https://superuser.com/questions/945159/is-it-possible-to-get-windows-10-upgrade-as-an-iso-image-to-make-a-bootable-ins)).

Comment: Upgrade from windows 7 to 10 depends on windows updates, which without win 7 install will not be present. I'd recommend installing Win 7 first, it doesn't take that much time anyway.

Comment: Windows 10 1511 installation media allow you to use Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 8.1 to install Windows 10.  There is no direct path  to Windows 10 from Windows Vista, which means you won't even be able to keep your personal files, so you are better of booting to the installation media or upgrading the Vista installations to Windows 7.

Comment: "Can I successfully run this installer using an unused Windows 7 Professional OEM key, " Yes, starting with W10 1511 it will accept W7 and W8 keys during a clean install.